# After changing the last dropdown from 3 drop down, completely a copy of the all 3 drop down comes without having the first dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below is my 3 drop down section.I want to change in the 3rd drop down which having the values AND/OR. After changing the drop down there will be another clone of all the 3 same drop down filed will come and condition is only in the clone section for first select field the value shouldn't be there which was previously chosen(If I choosen Category in first select, then in the clone section for first select field there willn't be any Category section).

Also as per there is 3 option value in first select and those are (Category, Genre and Cast), so while on changing the AND/OR section we can only clone 2 more div, except the first one.

Also, if we already chosen Category section in first section and then we choose AND/OR option field then other 2 option will vanish from the first select field. Similarly it will proceed like this

I have got some how to clone it, but can't do exactly what our requirement. Below is my HTML and js code.

```
**HTML**

<div class="radio">
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="specific_content" value="2">
<label for="test2">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="content-form" name="content_form">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
        <option value="category">Category</option>
        <option value="genre">Genre</option>
        <option value="cast">Cast</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control content-type-section" id="content_type" name="content_type" disabled="disabled" onchange="removeDisableFromCondition(this)">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
        <option value="123">Movie</option>
        <option value="321">TV</option>
        <option value="345">Cast</option>
        <option value="987">Genre</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control condition-section" id="sel1" name="conditions" disabled="disabled" onchange="showAnotherSection()">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Select</option>
        <option value="1">AND</option>
        <option value="2">OR</option>                                
    </select>
</div>
<div id="cloned_copy">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sel1').change(function() {
     var selectedVal = $('#content-form').val();     
     var target = $("#cloned_copy");
     target.empty();
       $("#content-form").clone().appendTo(target);
     $("#cloned_copy option[value='"+ selectedVal +"']").remove();
  });
});
```

[image]

[After choosing AND/OR select drop down](https://screenshots.firefox.com/1rJMzDqhyD4hVUtI/devstudio.billing.com)

Comment: Could you explain what use case this would serve? It seems you are trying to give the user the ability to build complex queries, but I cannot picture what useful 3-part query this could yield (even if it worked as intended).

Comment: @MajidFouladpour, The clone is working for the first time only. While I change again the AND/OR option field in the newly clone section no more clone is coming.

Comment: that's becouse all of them have the same id, and the jquery selecto by id only returns the first element, if you want to acomplish this you should change your logic to refer the item which has been changed with $(this) and select the html you want to clone